# Add Language translation text in magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, localisation, language, i18n

I have added the new field in Customer navigation section near the `Sign In`, For that new field I need to fr_FR translation where I need to add the translation text? Those translation files are working from which file please tell me.

Answer (score 3):

have you used this syntax where you put your text?

**Template file:**

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Your text') ?>
```

**Knockout file:**

```
data-bind="i18n: 'Your text'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can installed French Language pack
https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-french-language-pack

Or you can Create language file at below path and add translation text.
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/i18n/fr_FR.csv

Comment: I have already installed all languages translated but my custom language text is not translated that's the problem

Comment: is rest of things are translated?

Comment: have u set language from admin configuration?

Comment: Yes rest of things translated

Comment: I have one added one custom text that one is not translated

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ib8abs screenshot

Answer (score 1):

**Not tested**: But You can try using `fr_FR.csv` under `/vendor/magento/module-customer/i18n` directory and check the translation.

Hope that may help you.

Comment: In that folder that folder I have added that text is exit but translation not working

Comment: If I edited that existing text means that one also not coming I don't know where this text is loading